# How to determine whether $a_n=\frac{n\cos(n\pi)}{2n-1}$ converges or diverges

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

I know I can use the alternating series test, which would be $\frac{a_n+1}{a_n}$. I have that $\frac{(n+1)\cos(n+1)\pi}{2n+1}\cdot\frac{2n-1}{n\cos(n\pi)}$

Is there an easier way to determine divergence or convergence than using the alternating series test?

Answer (score 3):

$$cos(\pi)=-1$$
$$\cos(2\pi)=1$$
$$\cos(3\pi)=-1$$
$$\cos(2k\pi)=1$$
$$\cos((2k+1)\pi)=-1$$

thus the general term of your series is
$$a_n=\frac{(-1)^nn}{2n-1}$$
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}|a_n|=\frac 12$$

$$\implies \lim_{n\to+\infty} a_n\ne 0$$
$$\implies \sum a_n \text{ diverges}$$

Comment: $\sum a_n$ diverges as $\lim a_n \neq 0$ sir

Comment: sir $(a_n)$ diverges both as a sequence and as a series.

Answer (score 2):

The sequence is divergent. If $n$ is odd, then $a_n = - \dfrac{n}{2n-1} \to -1/2$ while if $n$ is even $a_n = \dfrac{n}{2n-1} \to 1/2$. Since we have found two subsequences of $(a_n)$ that converge to different values, then the sequences $(a_n)$ is divergent. QED